# C++ Can't figure out why its giving false positive (newbie)

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean-expression, logical-or

Hey so I recently started learning C++ and I can't figure out why this problem is giving a false positive all the time.

Maybe someone can help?

```
// [Included stuff]

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int erg = 5;
    int inp;

    cout << "Answer: 3 + 2: "; 
    cin >> inp;

    if (inp == erg) {
        cout << "True!";
    };

    if (inp <= erg || inp >= erg) {
        cout << "False!";
    }
    else {

    };
}
```

[image: Image of the Executed Code]

Comment: `<=` means less *or* equal. `5 <= 5` is true

Comment: `inp <= erg || inp >= erg` is satisfied when input is literally anything

Comment: `(inp <= erg || inp >= erg)` is always true. Every number is both "less that or equal" or "greater than or equal" to any other number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in this if statement

```
if (inp <= erg || inp >= erg) {
    cout << "False!";
}
```

means that inp can be equal to any number. That is the condition is always evaluates to true so the enclosed statement

```
    cout << "False!";
```

is outputted.

It seems you mean either

```
if (inp != erg) {
    cout << "False!";
}
```

or (that is only confusing because too complicated)

```
if (inp < erg || inp > erg) {
    cout << "False!";
}
```

Or you could write something like

```
if (inp == erg) {
    cout << "True!\n";
}
else if ( inp < erg ) {
    cout << "False! Less than the result\n";
}
else {
    cout << "False! Greater than the result\n";
}
```

If you have a condition like this

```
inp == erg
```

then its negation will look like

```
!( inp == erg )
```

or more readable

```
not ( inp == erg )
```

that is the same as

```
inp != erg
```

It would be enough to write

```
if (inp == erg) {
    cout << "True!\n";
}
else {
    cout << "False!\n";
}
```

Pay attention to that semicolons after closing braces are redundant.

Comment: Okay so how to actually change it that it is working ? :)

Comment: @Verloxide See my answer one more.:)

Comment: if (inp == erg) { std::cout << "true"; } else { std::cout << "false"; }

Answer (score 1):

`if (inp <= erg || inp >= erg)`
means less than or equal to or greater than or equal to so in effect it always evaluates to true. Use only < (less than) and/or > greater than or use not equal ( != ) instead so code would be
`if (inp < erg || inp > erg)`
or even simpler 
`if (inp != erg )`

Answer (score 0):

The term

```
if (inp <= erg || inp >= erg) {
   cout << "False!";
}
```

is always true. The term `inp <= erg` is true for each value of `inp` in range of `[-infinite,erg]`. The term `inp >= erg` is true for each value of `inp` in range of `[erg,infinite]`. So the tem `inp <= erg || inp >= erg` is true for each value of `inp` in range of `[-infinite,infinite]`.

Wish you much fun coding in C++.